# gunicorn + zope error handling

Tags: zope, gunicorn

we are trying to setup gunicorn + plone. It works well so far, but fails to handle errors (404, 500 etc) and throws 'Internal Server Error' while it should return plone's error page.

Example case of requesting a page that doesn't exist is pasted below. The question is how should gunicorn be setup so that errors are handled themselves by zope/plone,  as other requests?

Cheers and regards

```
==> var/log/gunicorn-stdout---supervisor-JhaTfg.log <==
2012-05-24 01:41:16 [15137] [ERROR] Error handling request
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/gunicorn-0.14.3-py2.6.egg/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 100, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/repoze.retry-1.0-py2.6.egg/repoze/retry/__init__.py", line 90, in __call__
    app_iter = self.application(environ, replace_start_response)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/repoze.tm2-1.0b2-py2.6.egg/repoze/tm/__init__.py", line 24, in __call__
    result = self.application(environ, save_status_and_headers)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/repoze.vhm-0.14-py2.6.egg/repoze/vhm/middleware.py", line 106, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/Zope2-2.13.13-py2.6.egg/ZPublisher/WSGIPublisher.py", line 255, in publish_module
    response = _publish(request, 'Zope2')
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/Zope2-2.13.13-py2.6.egg/ZPublisher/WSGIPublisher.py", line 185, in publish
    object = request.traverse(path, validated_hook=validated_hook)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/Zope2-2.13.13-py2.6.egg/ZPublisher/BaseRequest.py", line 518, in traverse
    return response.notFoundError(URL)
  File "/home/user/testing/eggs/Zope2-2.13.13-py2.6.egg/ZPublisher/HTTPResponse.py", line 718, in notFoundError
    "<p><b>Resource:</b> %s</p>" % escape(entry))
NotFound:   <h2>Site Error</h2>
  <p>An error was encountered while publishing this resource.
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

On my question I forgot to mention that we are using WSGI Zope and gunicorn.

In our scenario, we patched ZPublisher/WSGIPublisher.py to properly handle NotFound exceptions (404), instead of throwing 500 Internal Server Error.

Turns up that Zope + Wsgi is still not so mature (at least on error handling).

Comment: you can and should edit your question instead of adding an answer